# DDR2 RAM not runs at desired frequency

Tags: performance, memory

My laptop has a Core Duo T2450 CPU with 2 PC-5300(333MHz) DDR2 RAM which are from same make. But the [CPU-Z report](http://www.filefront.com/17289289/Acer-4710-CPU-Z-report.html/) shows the RAM only runs at 266MHz. Is there any way that I can make it runs at 333MHz? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual on http://support.acer-euro.com/drivers/notebook/as_4710.html claims that DDR2-667 (i.e 333MHz) is usable on your system.

You may need to go into your BIOS and check the memory settings are not limited to 266MHz, or that the memory timings are not set and so preventing the memory module from using the higher speed.

Otherwise it may be that you need to update the BIOS from the page I linked in order to enable to higher memory speeds.

Answer (score 1):

If BIOS doesn't have the options to force 333 MHz operation, sometimes one or both of the DDR DIMM modules themseles have their settings programmed incorrectly in the SPD ([Serial Presence Detect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect)). Try using two different DDR2-667 DIMM modules to see if that is the case.